# Unable to run JAR file

Tags: java

I have Windows 7 32-bit computer with Java 1.8.0_161 and I have a problem with running jar file by double-click.

If I run jar by java -jar filename or javaw -jar filename command, everything is perfect. But if I run file by double-click I have error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

So I checked regedit and figured out that java.exe from JDK is running file well, but JRE is running JAR with error above.

And it started doing it suddenly on one-year-old installation.

Thanks.

Comment: Your Java installation was not terminated properly. Uninstall and reinstall both 32- and 64-bit Java versions.

Comment: @harrymc What!? You cannot run 64 bit Java on 32 bit bit Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Oups, missed that part. But a message for anyone who has a 64-bit computer: Some tools are only installed by the 32-bit version, so it's better to install both Java versions.